# Async Task update value every time or only once?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using async task to handle calculation in background. But i want to update my calculation value every time in onscreen. How can i do that using Async task. Any possibility to get an updated value in onscreen using post executed method.

```
public class HandleDataManuplation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...v) {
        //totalKm=gpsdataElements.Distance-Contsants.jobStartKm;

        if(gpsdataElements.Speed<0.4)
        {
            Contsants.cont_WaitingTimeInSec++;
        }


        if (totalKm<Contsants.minDist)
        {
            totalfare= Contsants.minFare;
            //tv_Fare.setText(String.format("%.2f",(totalfare))); 
        }
        else
        {
            totalfare= 110+ ((totalKm-Contsants.minDist) *Contsants.rupeeKm)  +(Contsants.cont_WaitingTimeInSec/60)*1;
            //tv_Fare.setText(String.format("%.2f",(totalfare))); 
        }
        return null;


    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        tv_speed.setText(String.format("%.2f",gpsdataElements.Speed*1.852)+" Km/hr");
        tv_JobwaitngTime.setText(Integer.toString((Contsants.cont_WaitingTimeInSec / 60)) +":"+ Integer.toString((Contsants.cont_WaitingTimeInSec% 60)));
        tv_speed.setText(String.format("%.2f",gpsdataElements.Speed*1.852)+" Km/hr");
        tv_JobwaitngTime.setText(Integer.toString((Contsants.cont_WaitingTimeInSec / 60)) +":"+ Integer.toString((Contsants.cont_WaitingTimeInSec% 60)));

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with onProgressUpdate(). It is a method of AsyncTask class

Sample Code:

```
  @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {

        //This is where you do calculation
        //for now I'm just going to loop for 10 seconds
        // publishing progress every second



        for (int i=10; i<=100; i += 10)
            {
                try {

                    publishProgress(i);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

        //This method runs on the UI thread, it receives progress updates
        //from the background thread and publishes them to the status bar

        // show progress bar here
    }
```

Comment: ya i know.. But it was update my calculation value every time in screen or not..

Comment: it will update the progress constantly

Comment: ok. i will check that bro.

Comment: i updated my code just see it whether it is correct or not.

Comment: i dont want any progress bar in onProgressUpdate. Because user want to see their fare and time and kilometer at every minutes. so that what can i do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to use AsyncTask

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         // Do your calcutlation
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         //update your calcultaion
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         //pass the result of Your calcutlation
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`onPostExecute()` will only be called once (when `doInBackground()`) finishes and returns its value.

You can call `publishProgress()` from `doInBackground()` everytime after your calculation which will run `onProgressUpdate()`.

[From the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> onProgressUpdate(Progress...), invoked on the UI thread after a call to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the user interface while the background computation is still executing. For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in a text field.

Comment: bro just see my updated code and give me some solution.